# monitor and alert when too many open files are open on MacOSX

Tags: macos, file-monitoring

Is there any tool for MacOSX (preferably El Capitan) that can monitor open files in the system and alert when too many files are open?

Not only alerting but also dumping the list of open files somewhere (a text file, if it's possible in this situation).

I participate in development of an application which can cause too many open files, hence the question.

Comment: So is that *too many open files* per process or system-wide?

Comment: I don't think it's a big difference. I already know that "too many open files" error appears when the known application runs for a while. I just want to have those files listed in a text file at the moment when the number of open files exceeds some threshold.